# Whether you need to specify the binding mode datatrigger

Tags: wpf, binding

```
1) <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PropName}" Value="True">
2) <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PropName, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
3) <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PropName, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="True">
```

Everywhere uses the first option. A second and third I almost never met. Do I need to explicitly specify the binding mode? Interests in terms of performance and memory leaks.

Comment: `DataTrigger` reacts on value never sets it so it's always one way. If you want you can set `Mode=OneWay` but not using it saves you typing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to specify binding `Mode` for `DataTrigger` because what it actually does is monitoring your  property changed event and firing appropriate action when property value will met condition (e.g. will be equal to `Value`). 
It can't change value so `TwoWay` absolutely useless here. Regarding `OneWay` - same story, there is no reason to block source updating because as we no it can't be changed from `DataTrigger`.